# Multiple $_POST[''] != '' (IS NOT LIKE)

Tags: php, post, filter

I have this code:

```
if($_POST['badge_id'] != 'USN' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'VA2' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'PET01' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'GLD' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'BR149' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'DK032' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'COM09' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'KH0' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'COM03' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'US8' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'UK118' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'SE044' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'ESV' OR  $_POST['badge_id'] != 'SGR' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'SG5' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO006' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO050' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO051' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO052' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO053' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO055' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO056' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO060' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO061' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO063' OR $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO064' )
                $error[] = "The ID IS NOT WORKING.";
```

But it doesn't work. It must filter for a input but now does he say by all the ID is not working

Answer (score 2):

Make your code more readable, more performant, and more working all at the same time:

```
$validValues = [
    'option1',
    'option2',
    'option3',
    'option4',
    'option5',
    'option6'
];
if(!in_array($_POST['badge_id'], $validValues))
    $error[] = 'The ID is not working';
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using AND instead of OR ? You want all the conditions to be true, that means that your value have to be different from value1 AND value2 AND ...

```
if($_POST['badge_id'] != 'USN' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'VA2' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'PET01' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'GLD' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'BR149' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'DK032' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'COM09' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'KH0' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'COM03' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'US8' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'UK118' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'SE044' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'ESV' &&  $_POST['badge_id'] != 'SGR' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'SG5' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO006' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO050' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO051' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO052' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO053' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO055' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO056' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO060' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO061' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO063' && $_POST['badge_id'] != 'NO064' )
            $error[] = "The ID IS NOT WORKING.";
```

Comment: Yeah i whas 2 sec ago thinking that ;# But TY Thats right :P

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your if-statement means that it will always return true (this is an example on what's happening):

```
LET a = 1

  (a != 1 OR a != 2) 
= (FALSE OR TRUE) 
= TRUE
```

Since you have so many badge_ids that you check against, I'd put them into an array and use PHP's `in_array` function.

Example:

```
<?php
$badges = array('USN', 'VA2', 'PET01', 'GLD', 'BR149', 'DK032'); // etc.
if(!in_array($_POST['badge_id'], $badges))
{
    $error[] = 'The ID is not working.';
}
```